# Terraform yandex_dns_recordset

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, yandex-cloud

Мой опыт работы в терраформе слишком мал чтобы найти решение, если это вообще решается тем способом, в сторону которого я смотрю.

В гитлабе при создании ресурсов "yandex_kubernetes_cluster" и/или "yandex_kubernetes_node_group" им можно задать параметр public_ip = true/nat = true.
В дальнейшем все это создается на облаке и яндекс дает им внешние адреса.
Также с помощью терраформа можно создать dns запись. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
resource "yandex_dns_recordset" "rs1" {
  zone_id = yandex_dns_zone.zone1.id
  name    = "srv.example.com."
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 200
  data    = ["10.1.0.1"]
}
```

Можно ли в data поместить адрес kubernetes, если адрес задается не вручную, а просто выставлен параметр **true**?
Пробовал:

```
data    = "${yandex_kubernetes_cluster.cluster-name.master.0.public_ip}
```

Но в ответ получал ошибку:

```
yandex_kubernetes_cluster.cluster-name.master[0].public_ip is true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно другое поле не `public_ip`, а [`external_v4_address`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/yandex-cloud/yandex/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#external_v4_address). Именно там, если верить документации, будет находиться внешний IPv4 адрес мастера, который вы сможете использовать в DNS в A-записи.

Comment: Да, забыл добавить что решение уже было найдено. Все верно, внешний ip адрес находится в external_ipv4_address.